# PHP-Trying to test for a 3-digit sequence of numbers within an array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to determine if three sequential integers exist within an array. I've tested the code on several PHP sandbox sites, but as they don't allow the use of fgets, I've tested with an array that I have pre-filled with the 5 integers. The code works just fine under those circumstances, but fails miserably when run with an array filled by user-input. I'm not sure where the problem is, but any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?php 
    echo "Enter 5 Numbers:";
    //{Write your code here
    $arr = array();
    for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++){
        $arr[$i] = trim(fgets(STDIN));
    }
    sort($arr);
    function FindSeq($arr){
            for($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++){
                while($i < 3) {
                    $a = $i;
                    $b = $a + 1;
                    $c = $b + 1;
                    if(((($arr[$a]) + 1) === $arr[$b]) && ((($arr[$b]) + 1) === $arr[$c]) !== FALSE) {
                        exit("true");
                    }
                    else {
                        $i++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    FindSeq($arr);
    echo "false";
?>
```

Comment: _" fails miserably when run with an array filled by user-input"_?

Comment: When the script is run as-is, it cycles through and defaults to "false".

Comment: If you're having trouble with user input, use functions like `print_r()` to see exactly what the user input is, and whether or not it's actually what you're expecting it to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lines are read in as strings, however you add `+ 1` which casts it to an integer.  Then you use a strict comparison `===` with a string.  Either use loose comparisons `==` or cast the values to an integer:

```
$arr[$i] = (int)trim(fgets(STDIN));
```

Comment: Thank you!! Aaargh...two days of pulling my hair out, over two "=" too many. Thank you, sincerely!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick way to do this:

`for($i = 2; $i=count($arr)-2; $i++)
   if(($arr[$i-1] == $arr[$i]+1) && ($arr[$i+1] == $arr[$i] + 1))
      return true;
return false;`

The loop numbers account for your use of $arr[1] as the first element of the array. Something prettier would be more general.